# while Deploying the Hyperledger composer into fabric for multiple Organization where i need to paste the CA certificate for org1 and org2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Open byfn-network.json and replace all instances of the text INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT with the CA certificate for the peer nodes for Org1: - use the following command to get the certificate from the .pem file so that it can be embedded into the above connection profile.

Copy

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt > /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt
```

But i am totally confused which content i need to copy and where to paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, an organization needs a connection profile. This connection profile has details of all the peers connected in the network as shown below:

```
{
"name": "byfn-network",
"x-type": "hlfv1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"channels": {
    "mychannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            },
            "peer1.org1.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            },
            "peer0.org2.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            },
            "peer1.org2.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            }
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "peer1.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    },
    "Org2": {
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org2.example.com",
            "peer1.org2.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org2.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "INSERT_ORDERER_CA_CERT"
        }
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"
        }
    },
    "peer0.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "INSERT_ORG2_CA_CERT"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "INSERT_ORG2_CA_CERT"
        }
    }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "https://localhost:7054",
        "caName": "ca-org1",
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
        }
    },
    "ca.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "https://localhost:8054",
        "caName": "ca-org2",
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, this file has the connection endpoints for each of the peer of the network. If you want to enable the TLS in the network, you also need to provide the TLS-CA certificates here. This cert goes into "tlsCACerts" section of the json.

So considering your question, byfn-network.json should be your connection profile. And when you run the following command:

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt > /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt
```

It will copy the tls-ca cert of peer0.org1 and paste it into a text file at /tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt.

You'll need to copy the content of this text file and paste it into "tlsCACerts" section of the byfn-network.json file.

There's a quite comprehensive tutorial for the same. You can find the references [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org).